# How to install modules in powershell core 6.1 on linux

Tags: linux, powershell, manjaro, powershell-core

I would like to install [powershell-yaml](https://github.com/cloudbase/powershell-yaml).
Installing via [Powershell Gallery](https://www.powershellgallery.com/) does not work. The command `Install-Module` is missing on my system.
What is the convenient way to install modules?

using powershell core 6.1.2 on manjaro linux.

Comment: "The command Install-Module is missing on my system." - `Install-Module` is a PowerShell module.  If you don't have PowerShell already installed it couldn't possibly work.  Have you attempted to use the appropriate [PowerShell Core installer](https://github.com/powershell/powershell)?  You can only install from the PowerShell Gallery if you already have PowerShell installed.  I don't know enough have Manjaro to know how it manages it's packages.

Comment: Since Manjaro and Arch Linux use the same package manager, the instructions for [Arch Linux](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-core-on-linux?view=powershell-6#arch-linux) should work, but at the end of the time support for Arch Linux itself is community maintained so you might be better off going with one of the official support distributions that PowerShell supports.  I know enough that the information I provided is helpful, but I don't know enough about Manjaro (I only use RHEL), to submit an actual answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok with interactive session, then run `pwsh` and then run `Install-Module` in pwsh cli. You could also try `pwsh -Command {Install-Module -Name xxxxx -Force}` but not sure of the successful rate.